# Doing SUM in EXCEL VBA on variable columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a report in Excel, actually building it in VB6 to be generated in excel. As can be seen in the picture below, I have 2 columns, BOUGHT and SOLD. What I' trying to do is take the TOTALS of both and place them in the TOTAL row.

So I'm trying with code like this, basically first specify where I want to put the value

```
xlrow= 14
xlCol=2
ActiveCell(xlRow, xlCol) = (ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(B6:B12)")
```

' I tried this but it gave me a value of FALSE, not sure how to go about it
Basically I want to go into the BOUGHT total cell, take the sum of A,B,C,D,Other,None,Unknown and have it walk to next cell and take total of SOLD:

Have it in a loop so that it goes all the way to the end of record count (See below)

I populate the excel Headings (Packages, etc) with a recordset, and as I'm trying to make it dynamic (only do the total for however many columns I have and stop at the end). So this is what I'm trying to build

```
xlrow=14
xlcol=2
rCount=(g_RS.recordcount *2) 'because I have two columns (Bought,sold) for each Heading
dim i as integer
for i = 1 to rCount -1
     ActiveCell(xlRow, xlCol) = (ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(B6:B12)")
     xlcol=xlcol+1
next
```

[image]

Comment: first note is that you are trying to set a `R1C1` formula with a `A1` notation style. Change `.FormulaR1C1` to `.Formula` and see if it helps.

Comment: 1) get rid of these `ActiveCell` !!!   
2) I find it excellent practice to put totals on top (with frozen rows)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman it's still giving me FALSE

Comment: try this `ActiveCell(xlRow, xlCol).Formula = "=sum(B6:B12)"` Or if you want the value of the sum only to return, you can play with the `Evaluate` function. Since you are using `VB6` you'll probably have to call it from the Excel Object ... like `xlApp.Evaluate(Sum(B6:B12)` (research to get exact correct syntax.

Comment: I dont know why this is givine me FALSE. I'm playing around with it, but it's still false. No idea what happening. I'm just trying to find an easy way of specifying where your cell is xlrow=14, xlcol=12 (then I do xlcol12+1, and so on) - then xlsheet(xlrow,xlcol).value = sum of 6 rows above(B6-B12, then C6-C12, then D6-D12 as I continue to move the xlRow). but this seems harder than I thought

Comment: next to total is xlrow=14, xlcol =2 (SOLD). I'm trying to take the sum of A,B,C,D,None,Other,Unknown and insert it in 14,2. Then do xlcol=xlcol+1 and do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to help you gain an idea of how to code this more efficiently, here is an example. You can extend this through the rest of your code, but I believe it works for your situation.

You can certainly use the R1C1 notation for building a formula, but you have to properly include all the parts to create a proper reference. Use a `Debug.Print` on the string to see what it looks like if you need to.

> Added border formatting

```
Option Explicit

Sub GenerateTotals()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataRowStart As Long
    Dim dataRowEnd As Long
    Dim totalsRow As Long
    Dim dataColumnStart As Long
    Dim columnCount As Long
    Dim dataRangeR1C1 As String
    Dim i As Long

    '--- set these values specifically, or you can calculate them
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    dataRowStart = 6
    dataRowEnd = 12
    totalsRow = 14
    dataColumnStart = 2
    columnCount = 2
    'countCount = (g_RS.RecordCount * 2)

    For i = dataColumnStart To (dataColumnStart + columnCount - 1)
        dataRangeR1C1 = "R" & dataRowStart & "C" & i & ":R" & dataRowEnd & "C" & i
        With ws.Cells(totalsRow, i)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(" & dataRangeR1C1 & ")"
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).TintAndShade = 0
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).TintAndShade = 0
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
        End With
    Next i

    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: would it be possible to add a portal to this loop as I'm writing the values?

Comment: The general answer is... sure!  But I don't know what you mean by a "portal" or what you're trying to achieve. If the above sample helps solve your problem you can mark it as fixed, then you may need to open up a second question.

Comment: BORDER***** i'm trying to do the fancy one with one line on top and 2 on the bottom, or any portal

Comment: hey thanks a bunch, looks great. The only thing is, it doesn't underline the TOTAL part i have it as "A14" on my spreadsheet. Any way to include it?